# What does "sticky" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Could you please tell what is meant in this context by "sticky"? Does it mean that little girl was irksome as all the little kids use to be? Thanks a lot for help.

"He knew it was dangerous; the Nazis often left a young soldier behind to round up the strays, anyone coming to look for their loved ones. But in this moment Fabrice almost hoped for arrest, to be reunited with his family, even under these circumstances. He was desperate to know what had happened to them, where they had been taken. Would they be sent to a work camp? Or perhaps they would be released—some people were released, after all, and Marc-Antoine had skills that might be useful to the occupying forces. Capucine was nothing but a **sticky cherub**, barely five years old; surely she would not be seen as any kind of threat. "

J. Blackwell "Lost carousel of Provence"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The writer is using a metaphor to create an image of the child with the **sticky** fingers and face that young children often display while eating, especially when consuming foods that are easily smeared across their hands and around their mouths.